# set the value of ion-range but does not work

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have a `ion-range` from 0 to 10 and I set the default value to 5 : `question.min` = 0 and `question.max` = 10 `question.value = "5"`. The step is 1 (`question.step` = 1).

```html
<ion-item id="{{question.id}}" *ngSwitchCase=types.ratingScalePerso>
  <ion-range value="{{question.value}}" min="{{question.min}}" max="{{question.max}}" step="{{question.step}}"  color="secondary" pin="true" [(ngModel)]="question.answer">
    <ion-label slot="start">{{question.precisionMin}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label slot="end">{{question.precisionMax}}</ion-label>
  </ion-range>
</ion-item>
```

But the range selector stays at 0. 
Is it because I save the result in `ngModel` ? If yes, how can I do ? 
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code

In .html file:

```
<ion-item id="{{question.id}}">
  <ion-range [(ngModel)]='question.value' min="{{question.min}}" max="{{question.max}}" step="{{question.step}}"  color="secondary" pin="true" [(ngModel)]="question.answer">
    <ion-label slot="start">{{question.precisionMin}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label slot="end">{{question.precisionMax}}</ion-label>
  </ion-range>
</ion-item>
```

Sample data array in .ts

```
question: any = {
    id:1,
    value:5,
    min: 0,
    max:10,
    step:1,
    answer:'answer',
    precisionMin:0,
    precisionMax:0
  }
```

Comment: But now that I have done that, the default value is taking the previous answer. So for example, first time I have my range the default value is 5, then I move it to 3 for example and next time I arrive on the range, the default value is 3 and no 5... very strange..

Answer (score 1):

According to the Ionic 4 Docs, the **value** property needs to be a `number`. Your `question.value = "5"` is a `string`.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/range

Comment: I also tried to delete "" between question.value but not working..

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how Angular works, so

```
[(ngModel)]="question.answer"
```

actually ngModel sets the value of a particular component (including range).
If you want to do it using *value* instead you can delete the ngModel part and set `[value]="precision.value"`.

https://ionic-v4-19uyfz.stackblitz.io/action-sheet